# coding style for HTML i18n/l10n with variables

Tags: php, python, html, localization, internationalization

I have been working on web developement for quite some time now and I have always struggled to find a clean solution for a problem I have encountered during i18n of HTML strings, mostly anchor tags.

First of let me show you a typical problematic example. This is a frequently encountered string in HTML templates:

```
Welcome to my site. Check out our cool <a href="/products">products</a> 
you should not miss.
```

How do I translate this string while still having the following properties:

- Dynamic generation of the URL (e.g. using a router)
- A translatable string that is as readable as possible (so translators can do it w/o looking at the code)
- Because the string contains HTML, I probably want to escape some parts I insert (e.g. the URL), so I don't make myself vulnerable to XSS if this URL contains user input
- It should look as good as possible in the code as well

How do you translate your strings when they contain dynamic content and HTML?

Comment: One tip is to not hardcode your urls

Comment: I realize that is part of a solution (that is why I included it below) but it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I now want to apply i18n to that string, I probably turn to `gettext` or a framework function. Since I come from the PHP/[Joomla!](http://www.joomla.org/) world, I used `JText::_` before, which acts very similar to `gettext`. In Python I now use [Babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/). Both share the same problem and probably more languages, too. All code I share here is my way of doing it in Python, more explicitly, in my [Mako templates](http://www.makotemplates.org/)

Of course, the problem is: There is HTML in our string to be translated (and a URL, for that matter). Here are my options, which I will each explain afterwards:

- Passing the raw string to `gettext`
- Splitting the text into three bits
- Surrounding linked word with variables
- Using one variable that gets build seperately

### Passing the raw string to `gettext`

This one seems the first approach one might take, if not aware of the implications.

**Approach 1:**

```
_('Welcome to my site. Check out our cool <a href="/products">products</a> \
you should not miss.')
```

For this `msgid` you could now translate it, keeping the HTML intact.

Advantages:

- This looks very clean in the code and is easy to understand
- If the translator is keeping the HTML intact this does not produce any problems

Disadvantages:

- The translator has to know at least a little HTML
- The string is completely unflexible, e.g. if the URL changes, all translations have to be adjusted
- It does not allow for dynamic generation of the URL using something like a router

So as a conclusion, while I used this I quickly hit my limit. My next idea was:

### Splitting the text into three bits

**Approach 2:**

```
_('Welcome to my site. Check out our cool ') + '<a href="/products">' +\
_('products') + '</a>' + _(' you should not miss.')
```

Advantages:

- The URL is completely flexible now
- Only actual text for the translators

Disadvantages:

- Splits a sentence into three parts
- Translator has to *know* which parts relate together or he might not be able to produce meaningful sentences
- Not very pretty in code
- The `msgid` may be a single word, which can cause problems (beware of contexts) but can be fixed.

I used this technique for some time because I did not know about `printf` style strings in PHP (which I used back then). Because this looked so ugly, I tried a different approach:

### Surrounding linked word with variables

**Approach 3:**

```
_('Welcome to my site. Check out our cool %sproducts%s you should not miss.' % \
('<a href="/products">', '</a>')
```

Advantages:

- Single string to translate, a complete sentence
- Translator gets the context right from the string
- Code is not *that* ugly

Disadvantages:

- Translator has to take care that no `%s` goes missing (might be confusion as it reads like `sproducts`)
- Introduces two format string variables for every URL, one being only `</a>`

### Using one variable that gets build seperately

From here I had some different approaches, but I finally came of with the one I currently use (which *might* look like overkill, but I perfer it for now).

**Approach 4:**

```
_('Welcome to my site. Check out our cool %s \
you should not miss.') % ('<a href="%s">%s</a>' % ('/products', _('products')))
```

Let me take some time to reason this (seemingly lunatic) approach. First of all, the actual translation string looks like this:

```
_('Welcome to my site. Checkout our cool ${product_url} \
you should not miss.')
```

Which leaves a translator with the information what is inserted there (that's the [translationstring](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/translationstring/en/latest/) version). Second, I want to ensure that I can manually escape all parts that are inserted into the HTML. While Mako provides [automatic escaping](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/filtering.html#expression-filtering), this does not make sense in a statement like this:

```
${'This is a <a href="/">url</a>'}
```

It would destroy the url so I have to apply the `|n` filter to remove any escaping. However, if any argument of that is user supplied, it also opens up to XSS which I want to prevent. Not taking any risk, I can just escape *any* input (the same way good template engines do by defualt) and then remove Mako's escaping for this one string. So

```
'<a href="%s">%s</a>' % ('/products', _('products'))
```

actually looks like

```
'<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (escape('/products'), _('products'))
```

where `escape` is imported from `markupsafe` (see [Markupsafe](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/markupsafe#markupsafe)).

The final part now is dynamic URLs through a router: `request.route_url('products_view')`

To combine each of these possibilities, I have to produce something very ugly (note that this uses the `mapping` keyword argument of `translationstring` ([translationstring.TranslationString](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/translationstring/en/latest/api.html#translationstring.TranslationString)) but that combines all the benefits I want/need from translation:

**Final result:**

```
_('Welcome to my site. Checkout our cool ${product_url} \
you should not miss.', mapping={'product_url': '<a href="%s">%s</a>' %\
(escape(request.route_url('products_view')), _('products'))})
```

Advantages:

- Full HTML escpaing
- Fully dynamic
- Very good `msgid`s for translation

Disadvantages:

- An **extremely** ugly construct in the template (or the program anyway)
- The lingua extractor doesn't catch `_('products')` so we have do extract that manually

So that is it, this concludes my approaches to this problem. Maybe I am doing something *way* to complicated and you have a lot better ideas or maybe this is a problem that depends on specific types of translatable text (and one has to choose the right approach).

Did I miss any solution or anything that would improve my approach?